# Did snow leopards lose the ability to roar or never have it?

Tags: evolution, zoology, feline

Since [snow leopards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_leopard) are the only species in the genus [Panthera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panthera) that can't roar, was this something the others developed after snow leopards diverged or something that snow leopards lost?

Comment: Interesting topic. I found a recording of all the Panthera clade roars here, and comments like "roaring and purring are mutually excusive" and " Its vocal cords lack an all-important layer of fatty, elasticated tissue, which, in other big cats, gives the vocalisations an uneven rumble that emerges as a roar" but no information to answer your query, which is very specialized zoology/big cats info.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFCv02IGtn4&ab_channel=MeowMeowTV